# String to Map using java 8 Stream

Tags: java, file, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a file containing lines of format:

```
banana::yellow
orange::orange
apple::red
garlic::white
```

I want to read the file into a map with `key` being the left side of `::` and value being the right side of `::`

I am doing this to achieve it:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(myFilePath))) {
        List<String> myList = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String line : myList) {
            String[] pair = line.split("::");
            myMap.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, can this be further simplified so that the stream directly produces the map I want?

```
Map<String, String> myMap = stream.somethinghere ??
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can split the line inside a `map` operation and then `collect` it `toMap` as:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = stream
        .map(line -> line.split("::"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair[0], pair -> pair[1], (a, b) -> b));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of (a,b) -> b at the end ? as the solution works without that as well..

Comment: @Vicky that is just a `mergeFunction` in case there are multiple equal `key`s while collecting, it defines which `value` to chose. As of now (`(a,b)->b`), overriding the existing value for any such re-occurrence of the key. Just try adding `garlic::dislike` to your input list to see it working.